# Object Orientation. How does the representation interact with the object. Javascript in this case

Tags: javascript, oop

I am creating a tic-tac-toe game to play around with O-O code in Javascript, or should I say, pseudo-object orientation. And I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how a representation of an object, in this case, each grid cell being an object. How do you go from clicking on the cell to telling the cell object to place a mark here?

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/tic-tac-toe.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

And here is the unfinished javascript page:

```
var Grid = function() {
var cells = [];
// Todo: Finish 
const WINNING_COMBINATIONS = new Array();

this.setup = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cells.push(new Array());
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var new_cell = new Cell();
            cells[i].push(new_cell);
        }
    }

    var grid_div = document.getElementById("grid");
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            output += cells[i].placeCell();
        }
        output += "<br />"; 
    }
    grid_div.innerHTML = output;
}
}
```

There's also a cell class which has a mark property, an output property (for what will be displayed) and a setMark method. So if I clicked on a cell which is created by the output property, how would I reference the cell which was being clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was thinking of that. Adding an event handler to each of course to get the event, but using an XML attribute like xpos and ypos to get where it is in the grid. I just wasn't sure whether that was the best way to do it. So should I cal a method within the Grid class to call Cell[x][y].placeMark or something?